# How to set ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE in production with Electron Forge?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

Is there a way to set `ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=true` in my packaged application without a full blown Webpack setup? Lots of searching yielded no results and all of my attempts to set it in the packaged application yield `undefined`.

Comment: @chazsolo this question is specific to Electron Forge. Can we add that back to the title?

Comment: I use [this post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) on whether or not to edit tags out of titles. The tags speak for themselves for people searching for your question. In this case your edit seems more beneficial than before.